# which method i should use in this python code.. multithreading or multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to run the following loop n times parallely : i.e
one iteration should not wait for its preceding iteration to finish.
I want all the iterations to run simultaneously for all values of 'n' so that I can reduce runtime and get results faster.

```
for i in range(0,n):  
    api=str('some API string like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters '+offset+'')
    tag=json_tag(api) #API call 
    temp=tag["data"] #parsing json response

    for i in temp:
       place_list.append(i["name"]) #storing name field in list

    offset=int(offset)
    offset+=50
```

where

```
def jason_tag(string):
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET',string)
tag=json.loads(r.data.decode('utf8'))
return tag
```

I'm calling an API 'n' times which have an 'offset' parameter which changes every time when API is called.. 'json_tag(api)' returns json response of API call.From the json response im taking some data and storing it in a list named 'place_list'.

I want the output to be same.i.e. contents in list ("place_list") should be in same order as I normally run the loop. Which method should I use it to run the loop parallely multiprocessing or multithreading ??
How can i implement it

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do...

Comment: @AmitGold I'm calling an API 'n' times which have an 'offset' parameter which changes every time when API is called.. 'json_tag(api)' returns json response of API call.From the json response im taking some data and storing it in a list named 'place_list'.

Answer (score 0):

Get you max thread number, and divide n with the number of threads and if need balance it.
Then just pass to the threads the parameters start and end of the loop.

ex:

```
def function(start, end):
    for i in range(start,end):  
        [your code]
```

To save the result you can make some kind of list of results with some thread index to know what goes 1st etc. And then just concatenate it with order.